# Is there any way to add a note to an alert dialog box?

Tags: android, google-maps, user-input, android-alertdialog

I have a button that drops a marker on a map and when you click on the marker, you have the option of removing it by pressing yes.

I also have the time in which the marker was dropped in the alert dialog box. I did this by just getting the current time and placing it on the message parameter of the alert dialog box.

What I would like to do is that when I press the button to drop the marker, I would like to add a "note" or a string which the user would type up and it would be placed right below the time in which the marker was added.

I know that I can add an edit text outside of the button and pass that text to the message param of the dialog box but that would not really fit in with the app. Is there anyway in which I can add a note in which the user inputs and display it inside the dialog box?

Relevant code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Remove car marker?");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Parked At: " + dateMessage)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        carMarker.remove();

                        isparked = false;
                        park.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.parkmycar);
                        removePrefs();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your car has been removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

[image: note should be right below "parked at:"]

Answer (score 0):

You can place any layout you want inside an `AlertDialog`, using the [`setView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View)) method. It can be an entire layout, or a simple widget.

Answer (score 0):

Make a normal layout with your `EditText` and define a normal `Activity` which takes the notes entered into the `EditText` and saves it somewhere. *And* in your Android Manifest, where you declare your activity, use the following:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

For more info on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html